# pugixml generates no output

Tags: c++, pugixml

I try to read an .xml file to my C++ program using pugixml. 
The problem is, that not even the first example works.

My .xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
 <trk>
    <name bahn="Bahn 1"/>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="48.0815471" lon="11.2745363">
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="48.0815471" lon="11.2745363">
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
  <trk>
    <name bahn ="Bahn 2"/>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="48.08161089580602" lon="11.274945462810345">
      </trkpt>
      <trkpt lat="48.08161089580602" lon="11.274945462810345">
      </trkpt>
    </trkseg>
  </trk>
```

and I try to load the document using

```
pugi::xml_document doc;
pugi::xml_parse_result result = doc.load_file("kreisel_argelsriederfeld.xml");
std::cout<<"Load result: " << result.description()<<", mesh name"<< doc.child("name").attribute("bahn").value()<<std::endl;


pugi::xml_node bahnen = doc.child("trkseg");
std::cout << bahnen.value()<<std::endl;
```

Though when I call it, the output gets to `", mesh name"` and afterwards shows only empty space. Where is my mistake? Is it because I call the wrong names or something like that? As "Load result" I get "No Error", so the file should be loaded, doesn't it? I found several examples and tutorials, but all of them use this to load the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file isn't valid XML (only one top-level `<trk>` element is allowed). See this [pugixml error handling example](http://pugixml.org/docs/samples/load_error_handling.cpp).

If you want to have more than one `<trk>` they need to be wrapped in a single top level `<trks>` element.

Edit: Missed the part about there being no error. Perhaps pugixml is being tolerant here and the real problem is that `<trk>` is considered a child of the document node. So, instead of `doc.child("name")` try `doc.child("trk").child("name")`.

Comment: Your edit is correct - pugixml is tolerant to multiple root-level elements (which is surprisingly common), but the document object is a separate node.